# WPF: Databinding a dictionary property

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a UserControl with a property of type Dictionary, called `HighlightedDates`. The property holds a set of dates, with a tool tip string for each date, and it works fine when set from code.

I want to bind the `HighlightedDates` property to a view model property, DatesWithNotes, of the same type, using this markup:

```
<MyControls:MyCalendar SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate}"
                       HighlightedDates="{Binding DatesWithNotes}" />
```

Unfortunately, I get this exception when I try to do that:

A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Value' property of type 'DictionaryEntry'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

It looks like WPF is trying to bind an individual entry, not the Dictionary itself.

As an alternative, I am looking at having the view model push each new value added to its dictionary out to the user control's dictionary, which seems awfully clumsy. And that brings me to my question: Is there a way to make this binding work? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried replicating this (in particular the Dictionary part) and it seems to work fine.  Basically, I created a UserControl with a Dictionary<DateTime,string> dependency property, then I created a ViewModel with the same dictionary property.  Finally, I used the UserControl in a Window, set its DataContext to the ViewModel, and bound the UserControl.Dictionary property to the ViewModel.Dictionary property.  It works fine and I didn't get the error.  So I'm thinking that this error is being thrown by something else.  Maybe you can show us the definition for the UserControl?

Comment: Thanks--I replicated your test, and I still get the same error. I have reproduced the markup and code below. So obviously, I am doing something wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem gets more interesting. Karmicpuppet attempted to reproduce the error using a simple test project--see his comment above. He didn't get the error in his test, but I got it when I ran the same test.

I have read quite a bit about problems involved in databinding to a dictionary object. In my project, I refactored to eliminate the dictionary and moved on. I haven't heard any other suggestions, so I am going to close out this question.

Comment: Your view model is exposing `MonthNotes`, but you are binging to `MonthDates`:                                      `MyDictionary="{Binding Path=MonthDates...`

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a bug in the VS2010 WPF designer that can cause this error message to appear, even when the binding works just fine at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is already quite old question, the error "A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Value' property of type 'DictionaryEntry'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject." could be thrown just because the DependencyProperty isn't set as `static`.

This is something I get to fight with once in a while, just to notice that the `static` keyword is missing. It's so easy to go unnoticed, especially when there's the `readonly` keyword also.